# Starting WSL Ubuntu fails with error: 0x80370102

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

```
Installing, this may take a few minutes...
WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x80370102
Please enable the Virtual Machine Platform Windows feature and ensure virtualization is enabled in the BIOS.
For information please visit https://aka.ms/enablevirtualization
Press any key to continue...
```

[image: screen capture]

Comment: This is a Windows error. Did you follow the link given ? Or try pressing 'any key" to go on ?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  As @SorenA mentioned, your question doesn't include any information on what you've tried.  The error links to a page with help on how to correct this, but you don't mention what you've tried and what the results were.  Please [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1506892/edit) to include as much information as you can to help others help you!  Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Enable WSL in Windows Features and make sure to have virtualization features enabled in BIOS. You need to reboot after enabling it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).